# Error when configuring IRKernel from within R for Anacode

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I followed [this link](https://richpauloo.github.io/2018-05-16-Installing-the-R-kernel-in-Jupyter-Lab/) for installing the R kernel in Jupyter Lab. However, when I got to the last step for macbook, I received this error:

> Error in IRkernel::installspec() :
> jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
> In addition: Warning message:
> In system2("jupyter", c("kernelspec", "--version"), FALSE, FALSE) :
> error in running command

I tried to re-install Anaconda again, but this did not help.